# How to return the same error response from a Proxy

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

There is an endpoint which returns below response on certain scenarios.

```
{
"error": "invalid_client"
}
```

But I have developed a proxy which calls the same endpoint and returning error generated from the endpoint. but instead of above response i'm getting.

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (/home/ahkamn/Sysco New projects/ecm-auth-service/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/home/ahkamn/Sysco New projects/ecm-auth-service/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/ahkamn/Sysco New projects/ecm-auth-service/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:201:15)\n    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1130:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:17)",
    "config": {
        "url": "https://ecm-auth-dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token",
        "method": "post",
        "data": "grant_type=client_credentialss&client_id=12345",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            "Authorization": "Basic cfdW356",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.19.2",
            "Content-Length": 67
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1
    }
}
}
```

My proxy code is,

```
const { grant_type, client_id } = req.body;
const { authorization } = req.headers;
const cognitoURL = process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN_URL;

try {
// ProxyPramUtil.validateProxyParams({ grant_type, client_id, authorization });
// eslint-disable-next-line global-require
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cognitoResponse = await axios.post(cognitoURL, querystring.stringify({
  grant_type,
  client_id,
}), {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    Authorization: authorization,
  },
});

res.send(cognitoResponse.data);
} catch (error) {
res.send({
  error,
  });
 }
});
```

Please help if you can. FYI I'm getting correct response for not error scenarios